# 128-bit vector addition with Cuda, performance issue

Tags: vector, cuda

I want to add 128-bit vectors with carry. My 128-bit version (`addKernel128` in the code below) is twice slower than the basic 32-bit version (`addKernel32` below). 
Do I have memory coalescing problems ? How can I get better performance ?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>

#define UADDO(c, a, b) asm volatile("add.cc.u32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(c) : "r"(a) , "r"(b));
#define UADDC(c, a, b) asm volatile("addc.cc.u32 %0, %1, %2;" : "=r"(c) : "r"(a) , "r"(b));

__global__ void addKernel32(unsigned int *c, const unsigned int *a, const unsigned int *b, const int size)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  while (tid < size)
  {
    c[tid] = a[tid] + b[tid];
    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  }
}

__global__ void addKernel128(unsigned *c, const unsigned *a, const unsigned *b, const int size)
{
  int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

  while (tid < size / 4)
  {
    uint4 a4 = ((const uint4 *)a)[tid],
          b4 = ((const uint4 *)b)[tid],
          c4;

    UADDO(c4.x, a4.x, b4.x)
    UADDC(c4.y, a4.y, b4.y) // add with carry
    UADDC(c4.z, a4.z, b4.z) // add with carry
    UADDC(c4.w, a4.w, b4.w) // add with carry (no overflow checking for clarity)

    ((uint4 *)c)[tid] = c4;

    tid += blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  }
}

int main()
{
  const int size = 10000000; // 10 million

  unsigned int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;

  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, size * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_b, size * sizeof(int));
  cudaMalloc((void**)&d_c, size * sizeof(int));

  cudaMemset(d_a, 1, size * sizeof(int)); // dummy init just for the example
  cudaMemset(d_b, 2, size * sizeof(int)); // dummy init just for the example
  cudaMemset(d_c, 0, size * sizeof(int));

  int nbThreads = 512;
  int nbBlocks = 1024; // for example

  cudaEvent_t start, stop;
  cudaEventCreate(&start);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop);
  cudaEventRecord(start);

  addKernel128<<<nbBlocks, nbThreads>>>(d_c, d_a, d_b, size);

  cudaEventRecord(stop);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  float m = 0;
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&m, start, stop);

  cudaFree(d_c);
  cudaFree(d_b);
  cudaFree(d_a);
  cudaDeviceReset();
  printf("Elapsed = %g\n", m);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 128 bit add requires more work, doesn't it?  Wouldn't you expect it to be slower than the 32 bit version?

Comment: Globally the amount of work is the same : it's true that every single addition requires 4x more work, but the number of necessary additions is reduced by a factor 4.

Comment: You don't mention which platform you are on (windows or linux, which GPU, CUDA version, is it WDDM, etc. etc.) which is pretty important for timing analysis.  With timing, it's also common to do a "warm up run", prior to timing measurements.  When I run a modified version of your code [here](http://pastebin.com/ybQYCNy0) (cuda 5.0, rhel 5.5, Quadro5000 GPU), I get results where the elapsed time is approximately the same (and in fact the 128 version is a bit quicker).  My guess is you are on windows, and if using a WDDM GPU, timing things accurately can be quite difficult.

Comment: And if you are under windows, as I'm guessing, please also identify if you are building debug or release version of project.

Comment: As suspected, I'm under Windows 7 with a WDDM driver. VS2010, Cuda 5.5, driver version 320.57, and a Quadro 600 GPU. The poor performance is observed in the debug version. The release version is much better, but still slower by 20%. Maybe we can conclude that measuring time with this environment is unpredictable. Thanks for testing my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing CUDA code on a WDDM GPU can be quite difficult for a variety of reasons.  Most of these revolve around the fact that the GPU is being managed as a display device by Windows, and this can introduce a variety of artifacts into the timing.  One example is that the windows driver and WDDM will batch work for the GPU, and may interleave display work in the middle of CUDA GPU work.

- if possible, time your cuda code on linux, or else on a windows GPU
  in TCC mode.
- for performance, always build without the `-G` switch.  In visual studio, this usually corresponds to building the release, not the debug version of the project.
- To get a good performance comparison, it's usually advisable to do some "warm up runs" before actually measuring the timing results.  These will eliminate "start-up" and other one-time measurement issues, are you are more likely to get sensible results.  You may also wish to run your code a number of times and average the results.
- It's also usually advisable to compile with an arch flag that corresponds to your GPU, so for example `-arch=sm_20` for a cc2.0 GPU.

Comment: And by compiling with the sm_20 flag, the 128-bit version is a bit quicker than 32-bit version. Thanks!

Comment: good point, updated answer with that as an additional recommendation